# `console.log('Any way to format code in a question title?');`

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, title

I was just editing/improving a question and the original author had written a brief line of code in the title of their question.  Was just wondering if there may perhaps be some way to format the code.

I tried using backticks but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no markdown support in the title, and you should be happy with that, else we would get:

> **bold, *italic* UPPERCASE `INLINE CODE` titles**!

Just strip the code formatting out the title and try to make the title clearer if it can use it (usually code-only titles are bad).